# r cut dataframe by factors

Tags: r, cut

Let's say I have this

```
+-------+-----+------+
| Month | Day | Hour |
+-------+-----+------+
|     1 |   1 |    1 |
|     1 |   1 |    2 |
|     1 |   1 |    3 |
|     1 |   1 |    4 |
|     1 |   2 |    1 |
|     1 |   2 |    2 |
|     1 |   2 |    3 |
|     1 |   2 |    4 |
|     2 |   1 |    1 |
|     2 |   1 |    2 |
|     2 |   1 |    3 |
|     2 |   1 |    4 |
+-------+-----+------+
```

I would like to `cut` by month and day factors to have this

```
+-------+-----+------+-------+
| Month | Day | Hour | Block |
+-------+-----+------+-------+
|     1 |   1 |    1 | [1,2] |
|     1 |   1 |    2 | [1,2] |
|     1 |   1 |    3 | [3,4] |
|     1 |   1 |    4 | [3,4] |
|     1 |   2 |    1 | [1,2] |
|     1 |   2 |    2 | [1,2] |
|     1 |   2 |    3 | [3,4] |
|     1 |   2 |    4 | [3,4] |
|     2 |   1 |    1 | [1,2] |
|     2 |   1 |    2 | [1,2] |
|     2 |   1 |    3 | [3,4] |
|     2 |   1 |    4 | [3,4] |
+-------+-----+------+-------+
```

I thought that maybe using `by` or `tapply` could be a way but I cannot figure how.

Comment: Please post code from R instead of ascii tables which are difficult to copy and paste

Comment: I guess one of the group by operations should do it `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(Month, Day) %>% mutate(Block = cut(Hour, 4))`

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4303162) for many suggestions on how to provide data in an R question. Most of the time, just posting the output of `dput(data)` is the best option.

Comment: Use `cut(x, c(1,seq(2,24, by=2)), include.lowest=TRUE)`

Comment: Cutting hour by month and day makes no sense at all. Or are they just supposed to be random names, like x, y and z?

Comment: @PierreLafortune I'll make sure to provide `dput`

Comment: @Hond Ooi x, y and z for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a sequence for each hour of the day with `cut` and replace parantheticals with brackets:

```
df1$Block <- cut(df1$Hour, c(1,seq(2,24, by=2)), include.lowest=TRUE)
df1$Block <- sub("(", "[", df1$Block, fixed=T)
df1
#    Month Day Hour Block
# 1      1   1    1 [1,2]
# 2      1   1    2 [1,2]
# 3      1   1    3 [2,4]
# 4      1   1    4 [2,4]
# 5      1   2    1 [1,2]
# 6      1   2    2 [1,2]
# 7      1   2    3 [2,4]
# 8      1   2    4 [2,4]
# 9      2   1    1 [1,2]
# 10     2   1    2 [1,2]
# 11     2   1    3 [2,4]
# 12     2   1    4 [2,4]
```